# Does the following code synchronously return a resolved promise?

Tags: javascript

Does the following code synchronously return a resolved promise with a value of `1`?

```js
async function foo() {
  return 1
}

const p = foo()
console.log(p)
```

Is it semantically equivalent to the following?

```js
function foo() {
  return Promise.resolve(1)
}

const p = foo()
console.log(p)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they're completely equal. Async-await is just a syntactic sugar.

Comment: No, the first is resolved with 2, but the second is resolved with undefined.

Comment: I deleted the original comment because there was a typo in it. My apologies. Is `const foo = async () => { await 1; return 2 }` equivalent to `const foo = async () => { Promise.resolve(1).then(() => Promise.resolve(2)) }`? Surely the initial `await 1` resolves to `Promise.resolve(1)` and the `return 2` resolves to `.then(() => Promise.resolve(2))`.

Comment: @BenAston No, because of the same reason

Comment: Ah, I was missing the `return` statement in the second version. Thanks